# Pin subset of MPI processes to specific resources in OpenMPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, numa

I am running a coupled fluid-structure code with MPI. Due to the program structure, the structure and fluid data is exchanged only between the respective master processes, that is, if I run

```
mpirun -np 10 ./fluidsolver : -np 5 ./structuresolver
```

this will run 15 MPI processes, where rank 0 is the fluid master and rank 10 the structure master that communicate, respectively. All other processes communicate only within their respective fluid/structure domain.

For benchmarking purposes, I want to analyze the performance of running both master processes on the same socket/NUMA node vs. other constillations, which requires pinning rank 0 and 10 to the same socket/NUMA node. I am using OpenMPI 2.0.

Example: On a 2-socket, 8 cores/socket CPU (`c00-c15`) with no SMT what I would have with `--map-by core --bind-to core` is the following mapping:

```
+++++++++++++ Node 0 +++++++++++++|+++++++++++++ Node 1 +++++++++++++
+ c00|c01|c02|c03|c04|c05|c06|c07 | c08|c09|c10|c11|c12|c13|c14|c15 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ p00|p01|p02|p03|p04|p05|p06|p07 | p08|p09|p10|p11|p12|p13|p14|    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

`--map by` and `--bind-to` do not seem to be helpful options in this case, since they do not allow a 1:1 pinning of selected processes to resources. What I would like to see is:

```
+++++++++++++ Node 0 +++++++++++++|+++++++++++++ Node 1 +++++++++++++
+ c00|c01|c02|c03|c04|c05|c06|c07 | c08|c09|c10|c11|c12|c13|c14|c15 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ p00|p10|p02|p03|p04|p05|p06|p07 | p08|p09|p01|p11|p12|p13|p14|    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

where `p00` and `p10` (the master processes) are neighbors within the same socket/NUMA node.

It looks like [*rank files*](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect10) will suit my needs, however from what I understood, they require a 1:1 mapping of *all* processes to resources.
Considering that some of my runs comprise tens or even hundreds of processes and run across multiple physical nodes, writing explicit rank files seems like a rather cumbersome and unefficient task. Also, I have to submit jobs to a batch system, so machine files are not an option. For the same reason, most of the time I cannot know the compute node host names in advance, which may be required in rank files.

Is there a possibility to pin selected MPI ranks to a fixed resource (core, NUMA node etc.) *and let OpenMPI take care of the remaining ranks* (according to a global policy, e.g. `--map-by`)?

Comment: what is the exact mapping you expect ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: As written in my question, in the given example, I'd like to be able to pin p00 and p10 to the same socket and leave the other to OMPI's "default policy". AFAIK, rank files require to explicitly pin *all* processes manually, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I am not sure there is a trivial way in Open MPI. but what about `mpirun -np 1 ./fluidsolver : -np 5 ./structuresolver : -np 9 ./fluidsolver` ? you might have to adjust your app, but that should be pretty straightforward, and will allow you to experiment/benchmark quite easily.